# ERC1155 not importing correctly

Tags: solidity, nft

I am creating a smart contract that inheritate from ERC1155 but I get the following error:

```
from solidity:
DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
  --> contracts/Contract.sol:52:15:
   |
52 | contract C is ERC1155, Ownable {
   |               ^^^^^^^
```

Despite importing it at the beginning (I've tried to import it with "@openzeppelin" as well but did not work.

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
```

My code for the contract is pretty much empty so I'm not sure where is the error coming from:

```
contract C is ERC1155, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;
    string public nameContract;
    uint256 public quantity;
    uint256 public mintPrice;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _icon,
        uint256 _quantity,
        uint256 _mintPrice
        ) public ERC1155() 
    {

    }
    // Implement functions to use on this contract
}
```

Also I have another question, let's say I want to create a collection of n different items with each having a quantity x that is not the same for every item in the collection. For instance 4 items in my collection with a quantity of 100, 50, 20 and 1.
Is there a way to do this? Is the ERC1155 useful for that or I should keep using the ERC721?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to open a new question for the second question

Comment: Hi, actually I found a way to do what I wanted for my second question ty though

Answer (score 0):

the issue is on your `ERC1155()`
as ERC1155 constructor needs `uri_`

```
constructor(string memory uri_) {
    _setURI(uri_);
}
```

and you're calling `ERC1155()` constructor with empty params try this instead and it should work:

```
  constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _icon,
        uint256 _quantity,
        uint256 _mintPrice
        ) public ERC1155("your URI here")
```

Comment: Hi, adding the URI and setting up the function did not change anything. I'm still having the same error

Comment: this works perfectly on my remix, check again https://gist.github.com/Aboudjem/18b8f78496ef41fbed89aabc521ee6c8

Comment: Okay for some reason it seems like naming the contract C will result in an error. I changed the name to CR and it's working.